# Need to show User license data

Tags: visualforce

We have the user license related list under Company Information as below.

User License list

[image]

I need to show that information in a Visualforce page. It is fine if we are able to show only this section of Company information.

Anybody is having any idea on this.Please reply.

Comment: I checked workbench.developerforce.com but i don't think this is possible. i can't find an object that corresponds to this table. Although you have a table that gives you the UserLicenses that are already used.

Comment: Fyi, there is the [UserLicense](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_userlicense.htm) object but AFAIK the TotalLicenses and UsedLicenses fields have never become GA.

Answer (score 0):

There are UsedLicenses / TotalLicenses fields from UserLicense object available only through API call and only available for organization subscribed for related Pilot Program.

If your question relates to usage of UsedLicenses / TotalLicenses fields, you may vote up for this idea https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000cJTEAA2 and also you may be interested in a managed beta package I created recently which may serve as workaround for this. It screenscrapes company profile page and gets number of total license.

This package includes a User_License_Extended__c custom object which contains Total License number and Used Licenses number ( and some more fields ), these numbers are updated whenever a user is activated or deactivated or user profile is changed assuming package is properly set up with necessary data

Install link for production-like org https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t580000001ENa

So the page you want to build I have already built in my package.
Also I am thinking about to refactor this package and create another package which doesn't need credentials.

More details and release notes https://patlatus.wordpress.com/2016/03/07/salesforce-uletas-beta-1-0-release-notes/